# Unable to create grpc + Cloud Run + API Gateway + Firebase Authentication API Config

Tags: firebase, grpc, gcloud, google-cloud-run, google-api-gateway

I am trying to add Firebase Authentication with API Gateway to access my Cloud Run service. I am using grpc to access the service endpoints in Cloud Run.

```
type: google.api.Service
config_version: 3
name: myapigateway.my-project.cloud.goog
title: API Gateway + Cloud Run gRPC
backend:
  rules:
    - selector: "*"
      address: "grpcs://mycloudrun-service.run.app"
      path_translation: APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS
      jwt_audience: "my-project"
usage:
  rules:
    - selector: "*"
      allow_unregistered_calls: false
authentication:
  providers:
    - id: firebase
      jwks_uri: >-
        https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com
      issuer: "https://securetoken.google.com/my-project"
      audiences: my-project
      authorization_url: ""
  rules:
    - selector: "*"
      requirements:
        - provider_id: firebase
```

While running `api-config create` from CLI, I am getting the following error.

```
$ gcloud api-gateway api-configs create v1 --api=cosmos-api --project=my-project --grpc-files=api_descriptor.pb,api_config.yaml
Waiting for API Config [v1] to be created for API [cosmos-api]...failed.                                                                                 
ERROR: (gcloud.api-gateway.api-configs.create) Wait for Service Config creation: API Config's backend has no rules. If using gRPC, be sure to specify the 'rules[]' under the 'Backend' field. See https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc-service-config/reference/rpc/google.api#backendrule for more details.
```

As you can see the rules are mentioned in the `backend`. So not sure what is missing. Also, can you advice if this is the right approach to use Firebase Auth with grpc. I am using the same setup as we do for REST + Firebase AUth + API Gateway in GCP.

Comment: likely wrong indentation.

Comment: I use Cloud Endpoints directly rather than API Gateway but I'm using Firebase Auth and gRPC like you. Your YAML looks good. It's slightly different to mine but the structure is fine. I have (required?) an `apis` section off the root where I reference the gRPC `package.service`. (see: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.Api). The only other difference is that I also have (required?) the port included on the backend address (`backend.rules[0].address: ...run.app:443`).

Comment: Yes the missing APIs section was the problem

Comment: But still unable to deploy to API gateway. The logs doesn't show any error description.